# ACPI Error in the Console on screen with Ubuntu Server 21.04

Tags: server, acpi, 21.04

We have buy a new Shuttle XPC Nano NC10UXA. But after install Ubuntu Server 21.04 i have every two seconds a ACPI Error on the screen. This is very annoying you can not enter anything because immediately comes a new error message and overwrites the input. We have therefore contacted the manufacturer and he recommends disabling acpi in `/etc/default/grub` (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off"`). When we make this adjustment, the error disappears. But the computer no longer shuts down properly when the power button is pressed. It simply shuts down without wait of the OS.

Is there no more useful solution here?

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.GLAN.GPEH], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6D due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psparse-529)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6D] (20201113/evgpe-511)
```

Answer (score 0):

This annoying message appeared on all my 4 Shuttle XPC Nano NC10UXA.
I had to add "acpi_mask_gpe=0x6D" to the /etc./default/grub file:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_mask_gpe=0x6D"

After update-grub and rebooting, that message disappeared.

Comment: What message kept appearing?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with this command:

`echo "mask" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6D`